# Unir listado de resultados en una sola variable con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

El desarrollo que tengo que hacer en Python consiste en tomar un archivo xml con el árbol construido de la sig. forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La última etiqueta como se ve en la imagen de arriba en verde es de la que tengo que extraer los valores de los atributos *Name* y *Value*; esta se puede repetir en el mismo nivel de dos a más veces con diferentes valores en estos atributos.

Las funciones que leen el xml serían las siguientes:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_xml = ET.parse('ejemplo.xml')
rootXML= file_xml.getroot()

def fragmentXML(rootXML):
print("File: ", rootXML)
for child1 in root: 
    for child2 in child1:  
        for child3 in child2: 
            for child4 in child3:  
                for child5 in child4:  
                   for child6 in child5: 
                       for child7 in child6:  
                           levelChild7(child7) 

        transformData(values)
```

Al tomar los datos con Pandas, meterlos a un dataframe y agrupar los datos, me los agrupa uno por uno y no todos a la vez; esta es la función que estoy usando para agruparlos y pintarlos en un gráfico con Matplotlib:

```
def transformData(data_final):
   df_dataXML = pd.DataFrame(data=data_final, index=indices)
   print(df_dataXML)
```

**El problema es que no sé si haya algún modo de unir los atributos (*Name* y *Value*) de Signal para pasárselos a Pandas en el `Dataframe` y me grafique todo junto con nombres y valores en la gráfica. Y no me grafique cada nombre y valor por separado como en la última imagen.**

He probado con listas, tuplas y diccionarios pero no logro unir los valores, como si por etiqueta fuera una sola entidad y así se pintara, por separado.

En seguida comparto un intento fallido con listas cambiando la función levelChild7 y transformData:

```
def levelChild7(child):
  nameSignal = []
  valueSignal = []
  if child7.tag == 'chid7_e':
    for child8 in child7:
        for child9 in child8:
            print(child9.tag)
  elif child7.tag == 'chid7_f':
    for child8 in child7:
        for child9 in child8:
            print(child9.tag)
  else child7.tag == 'chid7_p':
    for child8 in child7:
        for child9 in child8:
            print(child9.tag) 

        transformData(values)

def transformData(data_final):    
    df_dataXML = pd.DataFrame(data_final)
    print(df_dataXML)
```

El resultado es el atributo Name y Value y es algo que no encuentro como agrupar, ya que están separados por filas y por cada etiqueta que encuentra en el documento XML.

**¿Podría alguien orientarme para saber cómo reagrupar los valores de *Name* y *Values* y meterlos en una sola variable? ¿o decirme qué es lo que le está haciendo falta a mi código?**

Comment: lo siento no entiendo tu problema, por lo que veo, el  programa hace lo que dices y no veo algun error

Comment: ósea todo lo que recibes como parámetro lo quieres guardar como una sola cadena, no es así?

Comment: No estoy seguro de si entiendo. Tú creas todas esas tuplas que se ven en la primera imagen, y te gustaría que todo eso se fuera a un *único* registro en un dataframe?

Comment: Si @Christian es asi

Comment: me gustaría que en vez de por separado, se fueran a un único registro... ya sea que los reciba pd.Dataframe y los agrupe todos juntos o que vengan desde arriba de las primeras funciones despues de extraer los atributos del xml y lo mande todo junto @Esei

Comment: haz tratado con un `df = pd.DataFrame({" ".join(data_final)})`?

Comment: Si, probé con join de esta forma:
`def attribExtract(child):
    nameCANSignal = child.attrib['Name']
    valueCANSignal = child.attrib['Value']
    listValueCANSignal = split('\D+', valueCANSignal)
    numValueCANSignal = listValueCANSignal[0]
    lt = ["(" + nameCANSignal + ',' + numValueCANSignal + ")"]
    transformData(lt)

def transformData(data_final):
    df_dataPXML = pd.DataFrame({" ".join(data_final)})
    print(df_dataPXML)`

**Pero me sigue dando el resultado por separado**

                    0

0 (HMI_HMIMode_St,2)

                0

0 (ACU_DSP_St,8)

Comment: Si hay que explicar intentos fallidos anteriores, se ponen en la pregunta (que en los comentarios el código es básicamente ilegible si tiene más de una línea). COnsidera editar la pregunta y añadir el intento fallido junto con el resultado

Comment: No deberia de ser `groupby(by='Name')`?

Comment: No se si pueda incluir este comentario de solución o como ponerlo, pero anexo este comentario de la solución para futuras búsquedas que puedan servir a alguien mas.
Me parece que el problema era que me faltaba usar un método de ElementTree llamado .findall() y declarar los atributos en una variable de tipo lista, es decir:
`data_XML = [
        {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
         "Value": int(signal.attrib["Value"].split(' ')[0])
         } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
    ]`
Esta variable se puede usar en el pd.Dataframe para después plotearla.